# C- Program won't terminate after 30 seconds

Tags: c, time

We were asked to prompt the user to enter phrases, and continue asking them until they get the correct phrase needed, for 30 seconds. Here's what I've come up with:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void childprocess(void)
{
    int start = 30;
    do
    {
        start--;
        sleep(1);
    } while (start >= 0);
    printf("Time ran out!\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_tiChildID;/* Holds PID of current child */
    char word[100] = "cat";
    char input[100];
    int length;
    iChildID = fork();
    if (0 > iChildID)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (0 == iChildID)
    {
        childprocess();
        return 0;
    }
    /* Parent process */
    while (1)
    {
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        length = strlen(input);
        if (input[length - 1] == '\n')
        {
            --length;
            input[length] = '\0';
        }
        if (strcmp(word, input) == 0)
            break;
        printf("Try again\n");
    }
    kill(iChildID, SIGUSR1);/* terminate repeating message */
    printf("Finally!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem: after 30 seconds, it prints "Time runs out" but won't terminate. How do I terminate the program after 30 seconds? Any help?

Comment: why do you expect it to terminate when it is stuck in `while(1)`?

Comment: That is not 30 seconds. That would be 30 iterations. To get 30 seconds subtract current time from start time and look for 30

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, use `sleep(30);` to sleep 30 seconds instead of a loop.  The child should send a signal to the parent when it wakes up and only report that time expired if that is successful.  The parent needs to handle the signal and exit when it is received.  When the correct input is given, it could decide to ignore the signal so it isn't terminated prematurely.   Alternatively, you could simply have the code in a single process handle SIGALRM and use the `alarm()` system call to set a timeout. Or use one of the various more modern variants, but `alarm()` is fine for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you are using fork which creates two separate processes with two different PIDs. You are killing child process but parent is still running so program just dont quit.

You could have also used pthread instead of fork with remains in same single process but what ever you are trying to achieve is simple with alarm function. You dont have to manage any other process. Just use alarm.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void ALARMhandler(int sig)
{
    printf("Time ran out!\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void)
{
    char word[100] = "cat";
    char input[100];
    size_t length;

    signal(SIGALRM, ALARMhandler);
    alarm(30);

    while(1) {
        fgets(input, sizeof(input),stdin);
        length = strlen(input);
        if(input[length-1] == '\n') {
            --length;
            input[length] = '\0';
        }           
        if (strcmp(word,input) == 0)
            break;
        printf("Try again\n");
    }

    /* terminate repeating message */
    printf("Finally!\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

Hope it helps !!